# Javascript - Why this piece of Angular JS code for dependable drop-down is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I am trying to implement a country-city dependable drop-down using AngularJS

```
<div>
        Country:
        </br>
        <select data-ng-model="country" ng-options="country.name for country in countries" data-ng-change="updateCountry(country)">
            <option value="">Select country</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        City</br>
        <select data-ng-model="city" data-ng-options="city.name for city in countryItem">
            <option value="">Select city</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Controller Code

```
   $scope.updateCountry = function(selectedCountry)
    {
        console.log("The selected country is 
"+JSON.stringify(selectedCountry));

        HomeFactory.setTappedCountryData(selectedCountry);

        $scope.countryItem = HomeFactory.getTappedCountryData();

        console.log("The country Item is "+JSON.stringify($scope.countryItem));
    }
```

Factory Code

```
function setTappedCountryData(data){      
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));       
    selectedCountry = data;       
};


  function getTappedCountryData(data){         
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));      
    return selectedCountry;       
};
```

JSON Data

```
[{
        "id": "1", "name":"USA",
            "cities": [{
            "id": "1",
                "name": "New York"
        }, {
            "id": "2",
                "name": "Los Angeles"
        }]
    }, {
        "id": "2", "name":"UK",
            "cities": [{
            "id": "3",
                "name": "London"
        }, {
            "id": "4",
                "name": "Glasgow"
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": "3", "name":"Russia",
            "cities": [{
            "id": "5",
                "name": "Moscow"
        }, {
            "id": "6",
                "name": "St. Petersburg"
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": "4", "name":"Spain",
            "cities": [{
            "id": "7",
                "name": "Madrid"
        }, {
            "id": "8",
                "name": "Barcelona"
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": "5", "name":"India",
            "cities": [{
            "id": "9",
                "name": "Delhi"
        }, {
            "id": "10",
                "name": "Mumbai"
        }]
    }]
```

I cannot get the cities for a particular country in the 2nd dropdown. Where I am making mistake?

**Hadi Jeddizahed has solved the problem**

**Only problem is the code is not working in Chrome develper mobile emulator ( for mobile device like iphone6, Nexus 6 etc)**

Comment: actually your `getTappedCountryData()` function is not returning any cities , its wrong .correcting it will fix the problem or try below answers for better practices.

Comment: @Sachin bro One country will come as default in the 1st or country drop-down , let India be the default country. Again one city will be the default of the 2nd drop-down - say New York for USA, London for UK, Moscow for Russia, Madrid for Spain & Delhi for India. I am unable to implement the default Country in the 1st drop-down & default City for that particular country in the 2nd drop-down

Comment: change the question accordingly then or create a new a question for that.

Comment: @Sachin can you help me - how make one of the country say India the default country. There will not be any Select Country option - just by default India will be selected. Also there will not be Select City option , by default say whenever India will remain selected Delhi will be shown as default city. One can ofcourse change from Delhi to Mumbai. In this New york will be the default of USA & London for UK & same for other countries. When the default option of India will be changed to any of the other 4 countries a default city for that country will be shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this.
you can also do this in controller in simple way

```
 $scope.updateCountry = function(selectedCountry) {
    $scope.countryItem = selectedCountry.cities
 }
```

and in view similar to this

```
 <select data-ng-model="city" data-ng-options="city.name for city in country.cities">
        <option value="">Select city</option>
 </select>
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/7SuNPxEmmLrBnx16aMUn?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: brother it worked but i have some more request for you - One country will come as default in the 1st or country drop-down , let India be the default country.

Again one city will be the default of the 2nd drop-down - say New York for USA, London for UK, Moscow for Russia, Madrid for Spain & Delhi for India.


I am unable to implement the default Country in the 1st drop-down & default City for that particular country in the 2nd drop-down

Comment: it should be like this. `$scope.country = $scope.countries[4];`
  `$scope.city = $scope.countries[4].cities[0];`

Comment: how make one of the country say India the default country. There will not be any Select Country option - just by default India will be selected. Also there will not be Select City option , by default say whenever India will remain selected Delhi will be shown as default city. One can ofcourse change from Delhi to Mumbai. In this New york will be the default of USA & London for UK & same for other countries. When the default option of India will be changed to any of the other 4 countries a default city for that country will be shown

Comment: brother can your modify the Plunker . I can't get you

Comment: for this `how make one of ...` you can check the country selected in updateCountry function and base on init `city` model.

Comment: every country will have a default city , not only India

Comment: like this `var index = $scope.countries.indexOf(selectedCountry);`
     `$scope.city = $scope.countries[index].cities[0];` see here http://plnkr.co/edit/7SuNPxEmmLrBnx16aMUn?p=preview

Comment: Only problem is the code is not working in Chrome develper mobile emulator ( for mobile device like iphone6, Nexus 6 etc)